# CartoDB: how to let users update data from the map infowindow

Tags: leaflet, carto, sql

In cartoDB, I have a map showing public lands in a German city. I want to integrate a form into the cartoDB infowindow to let the user update the data table.

How can I pass the values from the form to the SQL statement? Should I call a php script or is it better to use javascript?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.